# When and if ETH converts to PoS who will receive the staking rewards?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper, exchanges

For ETH stored on online exchanges will the exchanges receive all staking rewards or will they be passed along to their users that actually own the ETH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an exchange and this is my gut feeling, for an precise answer I would ask your favorite exchange but :

- for an exchange to participate in the POS system it will have to put a deposit at risk to be able to bet : would they risk the eth they owe to their customers ? not sure
- would you like as a customer take the risk of the echange betting wrongly and riskinng your deposit ?

All in all I think exchange could provide such a service but will abstain from giving it. Now if they do it I would like to know how my currency is segregated, what's happening if a bet is wrong, etc etc

Answer (score 2):

With Casper, the account that puts up the security deposit is the account that will receive the staking rewards.

If the account is an exchange or a pool, it would have to distribute the rewards to its participants.  Casper is a protocol designed to generic and agnostic: exchanges and pools are on top of it and have to manage themselves.